# Fill a list of objects from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I know this is a basic question, but I am struggling with it for quite some time now..

I have a main form in which I have a `List<Filenames>` and I have another class that gets invoked by the main form. This class has to insert some entries in my `List<Filenames>`.

In main form, I have the list initialized as:

```
public List<Filenames> filenamesList = new List<Filenames>();
```

And in the other class I do:

```
MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
mainForm.filenamesList.Clear();

//then I have a for loop in which I perform some changes

mainForm.filenamesList.Add(new Filenames { name = "filename1", id = 1 } );
//it works until here and a new Filenames is added to the list
//then we go back to the main form
```

The problem is that now the `List<Filenames>` is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please post the code you make the invocation?

Comment: You're creating new instance of `MainForm`. I guess you need to do it with the existing instance.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I get it. How do I use the existing instance?

Comment: Ideally you should pass it to the class where you need it. If you need Hack: `MainForm mainForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<MainForm>().First();`

Comment: I'll suggest you [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25245062/2530848)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this in the second form:

```
MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
```

You've created an entirely new instance of `MainForm` that has no reference to the list in the original `MainForm` instance. You're clearing the list and adding items to it, but when you exit your second form those items are lost.

You've got to pass your original `MainForm` instance to the new form that opens:

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    private MainForm mainForm;

    public Form2(MainForm mainForm)
    {
        this.mainForm = mainForm;
    }

    public void SomeMethodThatUpdatesFileNamesList()
    {
        mainForm.filenamesList.Clear();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

> I have another class that gets invoked by the main form

I suspect the problem is here:

```
MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
```

This creates a *new* `MainForm` instance, which is not the same instance as the `MainForm` that invokes the function.

I would redesign this so that the function you are invoking *returns* a `List<Filenames>` (or just an `IEnumerable<Filenames>` to be less specific) and let the *form* class worry about filling its `filenamesList` property.  Exposing data members of a form can get messy quickly since you need to pass an instance of the form to anything that must use the property.

soimething like this:

```
-- other class --

public IEnumerable<Filenames> GetFilenames()
{
    return new List<Filenames> { new Filenames { name = "filename1", id = 1 } };
}

--MainForm--

this.filenamesList.Clear();
this.filenamesList.AddRange(otherclass.GetFilenames());
```

Answer (score 0):

By declaring a new MainForm using the line `MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();` you are not referring to the same filenamesList. You need to get the reference to the first class, either by sending the filenamesList as a parameter to the function or by adding it as a propery in one of the classes.

If the "other class" is a child of the main form, you might be able to get a reference to the parent object, but this depends on the stucture of the program.